# Reading in Student names and grades from a file and outputting to another file

Tags: c++, struct

I am trying to read student information from one file onto another but i keep getting a `Segmentation Fault` error. I am not sure were it is that I am going wrong. I am trying to read in the first and last name as well as the test score in order to calculate the letter grade, and output all of that in another file. I will then try to determine which student has the greatest score and display the score as well as their name.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

// Set global Variables.
ifstream fIn;
const int MAX = 35; // number of students
struct STUDENTS{
        string fname;
        string lname;
        int testScore;
        char grade;
};

void input(ifstream &);
void calculateGrade(STUDENTS);

int main(){ 
    input(fIn);
}

void input(ifstream &fIn){
    ofstream fOut;
    fIn.open("students.txt");
    fOut.open("students.out");

    if (!fIn){
        cout << "Cannot open input file. Program terminates!." << endl;
        return;
    }

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        STUDENTS student[i];
        fIn >> student[i].fname >> student[i].lname >> student[i].testScore;

        // switch statement that calculates grade goes here
        calculateGrade(student[i]);
        fOut << left << setw(12) << student[i].lname << ", " << setw(12) << 
            student[i].fname << right << setw(4) << student[i].testScore << 
            setw(2) << student[i].grade << endl;
    }

    fOut << endl;

    fIn.close();
    fOut.close();
}

void calculateGrade(STUDENTS student){
    if(student.testScore >= 90 && student.testScore <= 100){
        student.grade = 'A';
    }else if(student.testScore >= 80 && student.testScore <= 89){
        student.grade = 'B';
    }else if(student.testScore >= 70 && student.testScore <= 79){
        student.grade = 'C';
    }else if(student.testScore >= 60 && student.testScore <= 69){
        student.grade = 'D';
    }else if(student.testScore >= 0 && student.testScore <= 59){
        student.grade = 'F';
    }else{
        student.grade = 'N';
    }


}
```

Comment: When you debug your application (what you should) I would focus here: `for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
        STUDENTS student[i];` I can assume what you intended to do with `STUDENTS student[i];` but it surely does not what you think. So, for `i = 0` (first iteration) it would allocate a `STUDENTS` array of size 0. Furthermore, access to `student[i]` will result in an out-of-bound access in _every_ iteration. This is, at least, an opportunity for a segmentation fault. (Btw. it results in a [VLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which is even not standard C++ conform.)

Comment: If you're getting a segmentation fault you can't be using visual studio c++, please don't add irrelevant tags

Comment: Btw. if you read, process, and write results for every student in a loop, (what appears reasonable to me) I don't see why you need an array (or any other container) at all. A single instance (e.g. `STUDENTS student;`) would do as well.

Comment: Sorry, to edit your tags again: VisualStudio is not VisualStudio code. These are two distinct products with different features (although for a similar purpose). As indicated by @AlanBirtles, I assume you rather use VS Code. And, beside of this, the IDE you're using is not responsible for the semantic errors in your code... ;-)

Comment: Do you think it would be best to use a while loop?

Comment: Got it, sorry I’m new here.

Comment: Your problem is not whether you use a `for()` or `while()` loop. (You can write equivalent code with both of them.)

Comment: Yet another side note: If your input file may contain less than `MAX` students, then it would make very sense to check whether input was successful (and bail out of the loop otherwise). So, with a little change: `if (!(fIn >> student.fname >> student.lname >> student.testScore)) break; // if input fails then break (i.e. leave the loop)`. Actually, (my earlier hint of dropping the array in mind), the loop condition is not anymore necessary as the code would now become able to process any number of students. (i.e. use an "end-less" loop instead: `for (;;)`)